# sonarqube configure for specific package or folder wise

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, window, sonarqube7

Can anybody help me to configure sonarqube for specific package or folder.
Because in my application codebase(maven based), there is multiple application code is available.But some application is not accessible and some app is handled by different team from different organization.So I don't want to work on that. My application is not differentiated by any module or parent/child architecture. It is merely differentiated by naming convention and ooops....
I have tried with below but not descriptive
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven
thanks in Advance.....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using maven sonar plugin . you can configure source path with property in maven like

```
<sonar.sources>src\main\java\your\folder\</sonar.sources>
```

If you are going to use sonar scanner . you can try suvanesh's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the specific path of source folders which you want to scan under sonar.sources.Refer below

sonar.sources=/path/service/src,/path/dao/src